# Inkscape for cartography : automatic fore color of texts for maximum contrast over background

Tags: inkscape, background, contrast, cartography

I have again a series of cities names on a map. I have a solution to [fill a background rectangle that can be semi transparent to make the text always visible, great](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120294/inkscape-for-cartography-fill-the-background-of-a-text).

What I want to do now is attributing a variable fore color to the text generating the maximum contrast, like the text in the bottom in this image:

[image]

What could be the way to automate this process in Inkscape?

Answer (score 1):

You can get something kind of similar, by using a modified Blend filter.

1. Type some white text, and make sure the text object is selected
2. Click *Filters > Fill and Transparency > Blend*
3. Set the source to Background
4. Open the Filter Editor
5. Change the Mode to Exclusion

[image]

Note: the contrast is not as strong/vivid as your example because effect is dependent on the colour of the background image. Also if the text is set to white, the effect won't work over areas of white. If you move the text over coloured areas of the background for example, it will change reds to blue and modify other colours to their opposites.

Comment: The solutions seems so great! but I can't reproduce it in  Inkscape 0.92.3. Select text, Click filters -> Fill, edit filter, mode exclusion. I see exactly what you have proposed and yet nothing happens. The background is a PNG image in a different layer.

Comment: @theworldisnotflat I used 0.92.3 to make this, but the text is on the same layer as the image.  Try typing the text on the same layer as the image.  If the text is on a separate layer above the image layer, you can also change the blending mode of the text layer to "exclusion" in the layers panel. I tested this, it also works.  Also make sure the text is set to a white fill.

Comment: @theworldisnotflat also can you check you changed the source to "Background" in step 3.  It won't work if you forget that.

Comment: my text was black, ok turned it white but still do not work; tried from a blank new file, add geometric figures, still do not work; tried on the layer of the png, failure; what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try the second method I described. Put white text on a layer above the image layer. Then set the blend mode for the text layer to Exclusion. I've just tried it, again and it definitely works.

Comment: I succeeded to apply the blend at the level of the layers, with expected result, but did not succeed at the level of the filters; the only change is the white text turning black when I set "Effect Connection" to "Source Graphic". Tested with Background at step 3, mode exclusion, same or different layers.

Comment: @theworldisnotflat - that's odd, because applying the blend mode at the layer level actually creates a blend filter. Perhaps it's just a glitch?