# How fill a text colormap as invert of its background

Tags: inkscape, selections, text-on-path

As the title says I want to fill a text with an inverse of its background colormap in Inkscape. I know how to do this in Gimp:

1. Right click on the text layer and select `Text to Path`:

> [image]

2. Go to the `path` tab and select the path which was just created:

> [image]

3. Make sure the main layer your want to use as back ground is selected, the text layer is hidden, and then use the path as selection tool by going to `menu > select > From Path` or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
4. now you can go to `menu > Colors > Invert`:

> [image]

I would appreciate if you could help me know how I can do this in Inkscape?

Comment: for those who end up here, one solution was offered [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Inkscape/comments/ax6q92/how_to_fill_a_text_comolrmap_as_invert_of_its/)

Comment: Possibly related question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120319/inkscape-for-cartography-automatic-fore-color-of-texts-for-maximum-contrast-ov/120324#120324 which I answered not long ago.

Comment: @BillyKerr yes indeed it seems similar, not sure if it is the exact same though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one easy way I know that works, since I just tested it.

1. Import a raster image into Inkscape
2. In the layers panel, create a new layer.
3. Type some text and make sure it is filled white.
4. Change the layer blend mode to "Exclusion".  Note: this basically adds a blend filter to the text.

Example:

[image]

Comment: This is an awesome solution because I can use other objects rather than text as well. Thanks you

Comment: One big issue: When exporting as PDF it exports the text as white!

Comment: I asked another question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/121087/inkscape-does-not-export-the-layers-blend-mode-exclusion-to-pdf) about this issue.