# Inkscape Printing

Tags: print-design, inkscape, shadows

I created a design in Inkscape and I was having an issue with the design converting to PDF. The problem is whenever I export it to PDF, the blurred shadow disappears in the PDF file. I need this solved ASAP because I need it to send it for print.  I hope you understand.

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. For me, blurring a shape works just fine when exporting as PDF.

Answer (score 5):

Inkscape's effects can suffer when you make a PDF. That depends on used PDF engine and settings. The same problem has occurred also with blending modes:

[Inkscape does not export the layer's blend mode exclusion to PDF](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/121087/inkscape-does-not-export-the-layers-blend-mode-exclusion-to-pdf)

As a first aid try to insert the shadow as separate object. Rasterize it. Edit > Make Bitmap Copy generates a rasterized copy. Set the rasterizing resolution high enough in the preferences.

Comment: Hey, I am newbie can you explain it a little? The design is really big and it has just small blurred shadow at the corners.

Comment: @SyedArsalan If the shadow is an effect, remove it. Draw dark shapes into the corners. Blur them. Make bitmap copies , remove the original drawn shadows. Be sure the blending mode in the objects panel is = normal for the new shadows. Test.

Comment: @user287001 - you don't need to make bitmap copies. Simple blurred shapes made in Inkscape work perfectly fine in a PDF exported by Inkscape. [See example here](https://i.imgur.com/ESYnOEl.png).

Comment: @BillyKerr the questioner got nothing. There's no evidence he didn't try what you suggest. I tried to write something waterproof which covers also the case he did as you suggested and got nothing.

Comment: @user287001 That's fair enough.  Although it would have helped if the OP had mentioned exactly how the shadow was created in the first place, and like you I suspect it's probably some effect that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you select 'rasterize filter effects' in the pdf export dialog, the filter effects will be carried over into the pdf file. I suspect that you accidentally unchecked that box (I believe it's checked by default).